# How to make a contour plot based on scatter plot colors in Python?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, scatter

I have some sensor data like this one https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iulianastroia/csv_data/master/final_dataframe.csv. I have calculated the anomaly points of ch2o column using the isolation forest algorithm. I have displayed the data in a scatter plot based on anomaly or not(anomaly color code is red and normal data is blue).
I have made a Scatter plot using Plotly like this:

```
    fig_outliers = go.Figure(
        data=go.Scatter(x=dates, y=df['ch2o'], mode='markers',
                        marker=dict(color=np.where(df['anomaly'] == 1, 'red', 'blue'))))
```

[image]
 Now I want to contour the blue scatter points, to separate them from the red ones. How can I achieve this in Python?  Something like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [matplotlib.pyplot.contour](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html)

I guess this is what you want

Comment: But how can I apply it on the scatter plot values?

Comment: Just have a look at the Documentation. X,Y are the coordinates where to put the points and Z are their values

Comment: I understood that, but x is date values and y are sensor values. I dont know what to assign z to. x=df['time'] and y=df['ch2o'].

Comment: z=np.where(df['anomaly'] == 1, 'red', 'blue') ?

Comment: No, because that results in z being red or blue and getting this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'blue'